# NSCollectionLayoutGroup: Trying to spread items like a normal layout

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

Using 3 nested groups in 1 section:

- group 1: animals
- group 2: colors
- group 3: size

MY GOAL: For each group, **trying to display** a spread items **like a normal collectionview layout** (horizontal & vertically)

`NSCollectionLayoutGroup *group = [NSCollectionLayoutGroup horizontalGroupWithLayoutSize:groupSize subitems:items];`

Getting wrong spread cells:

[image]

trying to get the following result:

[image]

I prefer to avoid calculation with customGroup code:

```
NSCollectionLayoutGroup *group = [NSCollectionLayoutGroup customGroupWithLayoutSize:groupSize itemProvider:^NSArray<NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem *> * _Nonnull(id<NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment>  _Nonnull layoutEnvironment) {
        return .....
    }];
```

Comment: Post a [mre] please.